# The driver executable must exist

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    
public class SeliniumTest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriver.exe");
    
    WebDriver driver = new Chrome driver();
    
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    
        enter code here
    
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get an illegal Exception:

> the driver executable must exist: c:\TestProject\drivers\chromedriver.exe

I tried multiple times to install the IDE and download the right version of drivers on both Mac and Windows, but I get the same error. Can someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");`, *what exactly do you expect this to mean*? In particular, *where do you expect the program to look for* `chromedriver.exe`, and why? Now, try **reading** the error message. According to the error message, where **is** the program looking for `chromedriver.exe`? Can you think of a reason why that might be the case?

Comment: Also: please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre], and *make sure you understand* each one of those, and use that information to [edit] the question and fix it.